# Google Cloud Build - How to backup builds?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-container-registry

I have `Google Cloud Build` and `Kubernetes Engine` set up in my project and I want to back my builds to another project. I am doing it in order to have a backup for a case of a disaster so I will be able to restore the builds.

I noticed that all of the builds are saved into a bucket called: `artifacts.{project-id}.appspot.com`

**Option I came up with**

Making a transfer of this bucket into another project.

This will physically backup these builds.

**Questions**

1. If the original project gets deleted will this be enough for me to restore the builds? How will i do that?
2. What other ways can I backup these builds?

Answer (score 2):

Cloud build creates a Docker image and it uploads it to Google Cointainer Registry.

Answer to 1:

yes, if the bucket is transfered from project A to project B if project A is deleted the images in project B will not be affected.

Answer to 2:

You can copy it from a container registry location to another or dowload it to your local computer.
To [copy the docker image in container registry to another location](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/managing#copying_images_to_a_new_registry) you can use the following command from your cloud Shell:

```
gcloud container images add-tag \
[SOURCE_HOSTNAME]/[SOURCE_PROJECT-ID]/[SOURCE_IMAGE]:[SOURCE_TAG] \
[DESTINATION_HOSTNAME]/[DESTINATION_PROJECT-ID]/[DESTINATION_IMAGE]:[DESTINATION_TAG]
```

The hostnames will be one of: `grc.io`, `eu.gcr.io` `us.gcr.io` `asia.gcr.io`

Project-IDs  are the source and destination project ids

and the image and tags are the ones you choose for the image